# rich:pickList with Ajax updates

Tags: richfaces, ajax4jsf, seam2

I have a RichFaces pickList from which the user should be able to select multiple items and it should be directly reflected on the backing bean. Right now I have no way to reload selection in case of a validation error or in case the page is reloaded. Is there a simple way to tell RichFaces that I want the backing list to be updated on every change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach to `onlistchange` event.

Using `a4j:support`:

```
<rich:pickList ...>
    <a4j:support event="onlistchange"/>
</rich:pickList>
```

Or, in newer versions, using `a4j:ajax`:

```
<rich:pickList ...>
    <a4j:ajax event="change" render="result"/>
</rich:pickList>
```

Or using `a4j:jsFunction`:

```
<rich:pickList onlistchange="listChange();"... />
<a4j:jsFunction name="listChange" />
```

Both approaches in the form above will submit the form causing submitting selected values. You can also specify additional attributes for `a4j:support`/`a4j:jsFunction` if needed (for example `ajaxSingle="true"` for `a4j:support` to process only pickList component (other inputs will not be validated/updated), `action`/`actionListener` to execute server side logic when list is changed, `reRender`, etc.).

Comment: My mistake, it was the missing <a4j:form/> tag around the picklist which let the ajax update die. But your answer is closest, congrats :D

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to declare your pickList  in a panel with `ajaxRendered="true"` ? This should automatically reRender the pickList

```
<a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true">
  <rich:pickList...
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score -2):

`<h:form>
       <rich:pickList value="#{pickListBean.result}"> 
            <f:selectItems value="#{capitalsBean.capitalsOptions}"/>
           <a4j:support event="onlistchanged" reRender="result"/>
        </rich:pickList>
    </h:form>`